# What kernel modules are required for FTP related connection to work with iptables?

Tags: linux, firewall, ftp, iptables, kernel

I am setting up restrictive firewall on my PC, which is running `Gentoo` with kernel `4.8.17`. I want to enable FTP PASSV mode for outgoing connections using this rule:

```
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

PASSV FTP works fine with `NEW` added to the above rule, which is too permissive for my needs. Also my config works fine on another box(with older kernel). I compared kernel options from both configs, but I can't figure out what's missing. So what modules are necessary for `RELATED` connections to work with `iptables`?

My kernel is configured with following options:

```
host ~ # zcat /proc/config.gz | grep 'NETFILTER\|_XT_\|_NF_' | grep -v "^#"
CONFIG_NETFILTER=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_ADVANCED=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_INGRESS=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NF_LOG_COMMON=m
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROCFS=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_EVENTS=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_FTP=m
CONFIG_NF_CT_NETLINK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XTABLES=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_TARGET_LOG=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_CONNTRACK=y
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_HELPER=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_SOCKET=m
CONFIG_NETFILTER_XT_MATCH_STATE=m
CONFIG_NF_DEFRAG_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_IPV4=y
CONFIG_NF_CONNTRACK_PROC_COMPAT=y
CONFIG_NF_LOG_IPV4=m
CONFIG_IP_NF_IPTABLES=y
CONFIG_IP_NF_FILTER=y
CONFIG_NF_LOG_IPV6=m
```

I have following modules loaded:

```
host ~ # lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by
xt_state                1543  0
xt_helper               1619  0
nf_conntrack_ftp        7270  0
```

My iptables looks like this:

```
host ~ # iptables -nvL --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
3        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22 ctstate NEW

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
1        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
2        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpts:1:1024 ctstate NEW
3        0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
4        0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp spts:1024:65535 dpt:53 ctstate NEW
5        0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spts:1024:65535 dpts:1024:65535 ctstate RELATED
6        0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 255
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since kernel 4.7 (so applies to kernel 4.8.17):

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/networking/nf_conntrack-sysctl.txt

> ```
> nf_conntrack_helper - BOOLEAN  
>     0 - disabled (default)
>     not 0 - enabled
>
>     Enable automatic conntrack helper assignment.
>     If disabled it is required to set up iptables rules to assign
>     helpers to connections.  See the CT target description in the
>     iptables-extensions(8) man page for further information.`
> ```

So doing:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/netfilter/nf_conntrack_helper
```

should revert to the pre-kernel 4.7 default and make it work.

Now the new (and more secure) method is described in this blog:
https://home.regit.org/netfilter-en/secure-use-of-helpers/

Comment: Thanks! The `echo 1` works, even without reloading. The 'new' one requires additional kernel module, so I will test it later.

Comment: Indeed reading the blog I linked to tells toggling the parameter after module is loaded is good enough (it just won't affect already present flows). I'll remove the reload line in the answer.

Comment: This deprecated (for many years) feature has been removed in kernel 6.0 . Using iptables' (or alt. nftables') explicit port helper assignment is now mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

I already used the `ip_conntrack_ftp` kernel module, but your `nf_conntrack_ftp` module seems to be the nftable version. It then may be ok.

However, to allow passive outbound connections you could try:

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --sport 1024: --dport 1024: -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

you should also tell iptables that he has to first track the FTP command channel (unpriviledged ports are only for data transfert)

```
iptables -A INPUT  -p tcp -m tcp --sport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 21 -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,NEW -j ACCEPT
```

**Credit:** [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/93554/iptables-to-allow-incoming-ftp), related to inboud passive connection (ie. iptables rules are added on a server)

Comment: Sorry, but that's not useful. First of all: ip_conntrack_ftp and nf_conntrack_ftp is the same module. 
Secondly your 1st and 2nd rule are already in my iptables(#2 in INPUT, #3 in OUTPUT), as I already allow all established traffic. Regarding your 3rd rule, it is for server configuration, so it does not apply. The 4th rule is also already covered by my iptables(#2 in OUTPUT).

Comment: I gueesed that the module was not causing issue, but as I wasn't sure I mentioned it. Considering rules, you're also right , I correct my #3 rule (dport -> sport), but you should also add the ̀ESTABLISHED` to your #2 in OUTPUT (also edited my #4 rule)

Comment: It's already there(although I admit that it's hard to read those overly long lines). My OUTPUT #2 rule allows NEW(from unprivileged to privileged ports) and OUTPUT #3 allows all "existing" traffic(RELATED, ESTABISHED). Looking at those rules I've just realized that my OUTPUT #3 is broader then #5(specialized FTP traffic), which makes #5 useless. It doesn't solve my issue though.